# Discord.js v12.0.1 channel is undefined

Tags: node.js, bots, discord, discord.js, channel

I'm trying to get a bot to read the name of a channel from an id. However I should be using the correct code for this.

This is my code:

```
client.channels.fetch('670722326664314911')
.then(channel => console.log(channel.name))
.catch(console.error);
```

Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null

Answer (score 0):

I have ran this code with no problems. It returns the name of the channel without any problems.

Please make sure the bot is in the guild and you use the right channel ID. Please check if the bot has permissions to see/read the given channel.

Also check if the bot does have any channels: `console.log(client.channels)`. Great way to start.

Comment: Thank you for awnsering. But i have found the issue. Im just an idiot and put that outside the client.ready handler