# When Using A Token I get an error while using others fixes it

Tags: javascript, discord.js

When trying to run my bot using a token I get this error

```
        guild.channels.set(channel.id, channel);
                                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at ClientDataManager.newChannel (/home/runner/GLADOS/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/ClientDataManager.js:81:36)
    at Guild.setup (/home/runner/GLADOS/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/Guild.js:307:68)
    at GuildCreateHandler.handle (/home/runner/GLADOS/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/handlers/GuildCreate.js:12:15)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (/home/runner/GLADOS/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/WebSocketPacketManager.js:108:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (/home/runner/GLADOS/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:336:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (/home/runner/GLADOS/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:299:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/runner/GLADOS/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/home/runner/GLADOS/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:789:20)
    at Receiver.emit (events.js:314:20)
```

When using a different token I get no errors and everything works fine.
Thanks in advance.
Here is the index code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { status } = require('./misc/config.json');
const client = new Discord.Client({
  disableEveryone: true,
  disabledEvents: ['CHANNEL_PINS_UPDATE', 'GUILD_BAN_ADD', 'GUILD_BAN_REMOVE', 'RELATIONSHIP_ADD', 'RELATIONSHIP_REMOVE']
});

client.util = require('./util');

client.on('warn', err => console.warn('[WARNING]', err));

client.on('error', err => console.error('[ERROR]', err));

client.on('disconnect', () => {
  console.warn('Disconnected!')
  process.exit(0);
});

client.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
  console.log('Uncaught Exception: ' + err)
  process.exit(1)
});

client.on('message', (msg) => {
  if (msg.author.bot) return;
  if (msg.guild) {
    if (msg.content.startsWith(`<@${msg.client.user.id}>`) || msg.content.startsWith(`<@!${msg.client.user.id}>`)) {
      client.util.handleTalk(msg);
    }
  }
});

client.on('ready', () => {
  client.util.handleStatus(client, status);
  console.log('[GLADOS] Started and ready to chat!');
});

process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, promise) => {
  console.log('[FATAL] Possibly Unhandled Rejection at: Promise ', promise, ' reason: ', reason.message);
});

client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

Yet again thanks in advance.
⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Comment: It says in the error that `channel` is undefined. Can you share some more code to see how you initialize `channel`? From just this error it's difficult to help

Comment: I think is because one of the bots is in the guild whose `channel` you are trying to access and the other one is not.

Comment: @fravolt Added⠀

Comment: Hmm it doesn't seem to be anything you've added yourself. I came across [this other StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60524532/discord-js-v12-0-1-channel-is-undefined) where a similar error occurs. An answer there suggests "Please make sure the bot is in the guild and you use the right channel ID. Please check if the bot has permissions to see/read the given channel". Are you sure that the non-working token also provides the correct permissions?

Comment: @fravolt its in about 33 guilds at this point, guess il check